Get orders with specific metadata in WooCommerce WC_Order_Query
I've used the 'woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query' hook to add some custom meta query vars to the WC_Order_Query function. However the added keys seem to be ignored by the query.
I've used the following snippet for testing purposes;
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query', 'custom_order_query', 10, 2 );
function custom_order_query($query, $query_vars){
    
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['zone_id'] ) ) {
    
        $query['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => '_wcgd_delivery_region',
            'value' => esc_attr( $query_vars['zone_id'] ),
            'compare' => '='
        );
    }
    return $query;
}

Now, when using the WC_Order_query I expect to only get orders in the given zone_id. But this is not the case.
When I request a list of orders using
`
$vars = array(
        'customer_id' => 2526,
        'limit' => '5',
        'status'         => 'processing',
        'zone_id'  => 4,
        'return'            => 'ids'
        );


$query = new WC_Order_Query( $vars );
print_r($query->get_orders());`
`

I get all orders for the given customer_id, not the orders for the given customer_id/zone_id.
What am I doing wrong here? I'm pulling my hair out... I've just followed the WooCommerce docs, but I really can't figure out why this is not working.

You can directly query custom metadata in your query using the following:
$orders_ids = wc_get_orders( array(
    'status'        => 'processing',
    'limit'         => 5,
    'customer_id'   => 2526,
    'meta_key'      => '_wcgd_delivery_region',
    'meta_value'    => 4,
    'meta_compare'  => '=',
    'return'        => 'ids'
) );

echo '<pre>'. print_r( $orders_ids, true ) . '</pre>';

Tested and works.
Related: Extend wc_get_orders() with a custom meta key and meta value

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Since I need to query multiple meta keys I ended up using this as a working solution;
    $args = array(
        'limit' => 1,
        'status' => 'processing',
        'return' => 'ids',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => $wcgd->region_meta,
                'value' => $zone_id,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => $wcgd->substate_meta,
                'value' => array('afhaal', 'parcelpro_dhl', 'parcelpro_postnl'),
                'compare' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        ),
    );

    $query = new WC_Order_Query( $args );
    $query_orders = $query->get_orders();

